# Is there a way to check integrity of Hyper-v configuration files?

Tags: hyper-v, live-migration

We are having an issue migrating Hyper-V guests. Source Windows 2016 Standard running Hyper-v role. Destination Windows 2019 Standard running Hyper-V role. Both servers running october rollup from windows update.

Guests created with Configuration Version 8.0 migrate fine. The remaining guests were created with Configuration Version 5.0 (server 2012 R2 if i remember corretly) and upgraded to 8.0 at a later date and all seem to fail to migrate erroring out at the start of the process with:

```
Virtual machine migration operation for <Guest name> failed at migration source <Source server name>
```

- If i delete and re-create the guest vm on the source server using the
  same vhdx file, the guest migrates fine.
- Restarting vmms doesnt have an effect.
- Restarting both source and destination server doesnt have an effect.
- Looking at Sysinternals ProcMon the Source server doesnt make an attempt to connect to the destination and fails early while reading the config files.

---

1. Has anyone come across bugs upgrading Hyper-V configuration versions like this?
2. Are there any tools for checking the integrity of Hyper-V config files or am i stuck with dropping and re-creating the virtual machines?

Comment: You could use powershell commands like `Get-VM` and other Hyper-V commandlets to dump all the various properties about things and see if you can find all the difference.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to simply get them moved to the new Hyper-V server you can export/import them rather than trying to migrate them.

Comment: @joeqwerty I'm thinking i will drop and re-create the VM's, If i have indeed found a bug in the Hyper-V config files i feel creating fresh configs on Config version 9.0 would be an appropriate move. While my goal is to get the VMs moved, my question is more about identifying any known issues with the config files and any tools in confirming config file integrity. This question having already existsed in my search results would have helped me. Hopefully it will help someone else who gets stuck in the same situation.

Comment: @Zoredache thank you for your suggestion, i'll make a copy of one of the vhdx files and build a new VM off it. then try and capture as much info using powershell from both the VMs and compare in Notepad++.